# overflow-x not working but scrolling the whole page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the div ".slide" to scroll horizontally only, but it appears that the whole body is scrolling and I don't know why.

If you scale the page down to mobile, and scroll horizontally you can see what I mean,

on the div.slide, I am using

```
float: left;
width: 620px;
overflow-x: scroll;
background: #ecf2f6;
```

You can see it [here](http://www.hexactly.co.uk/heyzap/index.html)!

Comment: This works http://www.hexactly.co.uk/heyzap/index.html

Comment: Can you clarify: you say that you want `.slide` to scroll vertically. Do you mean horizontally? It's just that your CSS sample specifies `overflow-x: scroll`, which suggests that you want horizontal scrolling...

Comment: @JonathanNicol sorry i meant horizontally

Comment: Yeah I suspected so! I have undeleted my earlier answer, which I think answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

You need to nest `.slide` inside another element, and give that element the `overflow-x:scroll`

Something like this:

```
<div class="slide-wrap">
    <div class="slide">
        ....
    </div>
</div>

.slide-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

I have thrown together a quick demo of the concept. jsFiddle isn't loading for me right now, so the demo is on CodePen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpGdo

```css
.slide-wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 320px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.slide {
  width: 640px;
  height: 320px;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-wrap">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent horizontal scroll `overflow-x: hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

**For vertical scrolling:** You have to specify a height for the div ".slide", and it should be smaller than the height of the content itself.

**For horizontal scrolling:** the width of the div ".slide" should be smaller than the width of the content.

For example:

```
.slide {
    height: 400px; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a height to the div.slide or it's parent container in order to set the overflow-y property to scroll.

Try this:

```
.slide {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ECF2F6;
 float: left;
 height: 300px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll;
 width: 620px;
}
```

Here I have set the height and the div.slide scrolls only vertically.
As for the horizontal scrollbar being triggered when the size is reduced to mobile - this is happening because your content exceeds the width of the page (2 divs with class app-ad).

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to get the overflow-x scroll, your parent element width should be less than the child div.

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
 <div class='slide'>Code goes here</div>
    Code goes here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{width:100%;}
.slide{width:200%;overflow-x:visible;}
```